# Splitting text file to separate files, and saving substrings in filenames; Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Searched for answers extensively, and have made a number of unsuccessful attempts, but can't seem to figure out how to do the following:

I'm using the following python code to save each line of a text file as a separate file:

```
with open("filename.txt") as sourcefile:
    for i, line in enumerate(sourcefile):
        with open("filename{}.txt".format(str(i+1)), "w") as txtfile:
            txtfile.write(line)
```

That creates filenames as follows: filename1.txt, filename2.txt, filename3.txt.  What I would like to do is insert a substring of the first 30 characters from each line of text in the separate filename for each line's file.

For example, assume that the first line in the original file is the sentence "I would like to get a pizza for dinner tonight." I'd like the filename for that individual line to be saved as "filename I would like to get a pizza fo.txt."

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to name each file with the first 30 characters of each `line`. To achieve that, you can use `line[0:29]`, which means "cut the string `line` between characters 0 and 29 ([start:end]).

Sample:

```
with open("filename.txt") as sourcefile:
    for i, line in enumerate(sourcefile):
        with open("filename {}.txt".format(line[0:29]), "w") as txtfile:
            txtfile.write(line)
```

Comment: That's perfect.  Thanks so much, Marcelo!

Comment: Any time @MJMJ.